# Apache reads from sites-available instead of sites-enabled - How to correct this?

Tags: 16.04, apache2

My Apache2 PHP7.1 now reads its vhosts from /etc/apache2/sites-available,
but it should read from /etc/apache2/sites-enabled.

Where can I change this?

TIA

Comment: You might want to include the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Videonauth's suggestion I have checked the /etc/apache2/apache.conf and seen that this line was uncommented:

```
 IncludeOptional /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
```

After commenting it, everything works fine again.

Comment: By default there is not such a line.

Comment: Maybe added after the latest update. I've just checked now and can see it on several servers exactly the same. Always on line 122. So thanks for adding the note. Now all confs are good to go again. :)

Comment: Which version of Apache is this? If it's really like that by default, it's a bug that should be reported.

Comment: Server version: Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2017-09-28T15:55:00